# Проблемы с кодировкой текста в php

Tags: php

столкнулся с проблемой - у меня есть переменная $one и в ней лежит текст из 50 символов, я вывожу переменную и все выглядит нормально и на русском языке, но в тоже время strlen() показывает что символов в тексте 89, проверил кодировку переменной с помощью mb_detect_encoding($one) и мне вывело что кодировка UTF-8. Так вот вопрос - если с кодировкой все хорошо то почему текст в котором 50 символов php видит как текст с 89 символами? как это исправить?

Comment: strlen показывает не символы, а байты. Один русский символ занимает 2 байта

Comment: А как проверить количество символов тогда?

Comment: `mb_strlen` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strlen()` считает количество байтов в строке (что совпадает с длиной строки в символах только для восьмибитовых кодировок, типа ASCII, КОИ-8, Win-1251 и т.п.). Для количества символов с учетом кодировки используйте [iconv_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv-strlen.php).